# MySQL innodb foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

Why will this sql not create the foreign key?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `flow_people`;
CREATE TABLE `flow_people` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `token` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unixtime` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `cams` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `people_type` int(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'flow_people_types',
  `comment` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`people_type`) REFERENCES flow_people_types(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1666 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

the table flow_people_types exists, it has an ID column.

I think I am missing something fundamental here, what is the problem?

Comment: Foreign Key constraints are sensitive to the exact data type in use on both tables, and the parent table must have an index on the referred column. Any existing data must meet the requirements of the constraint too. Without seeing the definition of your other table it's impossible to say why this won't work.

Comment: The columns liked by foreign key have to have the exact same attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [**MySQL Foreign Keys**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `flow_people`;
CREATE TABLE `flow_people` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` ENUM('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `token` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unixtime` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` VARCHAR(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dob` DATE NOT NULL,
  `cams` DECIMAL(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `people_type` INT(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'flow_people_types',
  `comment` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_flow_people_FPT` (`people_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_flow_people_FPT` FOREIGN KEY (`people_type`) REFERENCES flow_people_types(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1666 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```